# CoreData vs. SQLite vs. Custom entities and pLists

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have an app I am building in iOS, version 5. This app is using a WebAPI built with C# which calls SQL Server stored procedures. The WebAPI uses RESTful calls made to populate items within my iOS app which are returned to my iOS after an authentication challenge in JSON format. All of this works well. As a best practice I am interested in the best approach to consuming and returning data back to the database. Right now I have some custom classes or entities that represent the data returned from my service, for example, I pull all product data based on some category or subcategory and populate an array of type Product. This Product class matches the exact structure of the data returned, i.e. ProductID, ProductDescription, etc. I know this can be duplicated with SQLite and CoreData.  What I am wondering is this. Does it make sense to use CoreData, if so, what advantages will I see in using CoreData.

Also, a second part to this question. For arrays of items that rarely change, does it make sense to place those items in pLists? An example of this type of data might be something like Units of Measure where quart, cup, gallon, etc would be listed in a UITableView for the user to select from but it's not likely that the application will need these values updated often if ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [RestKit.](http://restkit.org) From RestKit website:

> RestKit can populate Core Data associations for you, allowing natural
>   property based traversal of your data model. It also provides a nice
>   API on top of the Core Data primitives that simplifies configuration
>   and querying use cases.

It seems to meet your requirements.

I would not go for SQLite. It may seem easier but using RestKit with [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001181) will give you a lot more.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the feedback, I will look into it.